# One Python script giving "user input" to another python script

Tags: python, input, automation, python-2.x

this is my first question, I hope I'm doing this right.
let's say I have these this file:

"simple.py":

```
a=raw_input("your name?")
print "Hello",a
```

but with a different script, I want to execute "simple.py" many time and giving the input automatically, that would work like:

"everyone.py"

```
run simple.py input=Alice
run simple.py input=Bob
...
```

to get
"Hello Alice"
"Hello Bob"
...

I know it's possible to make "everyone.py" run "simple.py" by using os.system, but is there any practical way to do something like this? And what if the first script asks for input several times?

It's important that **I CANNOT EDIT SIMPLE.PY**, only the other file

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why can't you edit `simple.py`? Is it just that you can't change its behavior? Or is it controlled by a third party?

Comment: it is controlled by a third party

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
print "Hello",sys.argv[1]
```

running `C:\Python26\python.exe simple.py Alice` would produce

> Hello Alice

There's a good example on how to get input from the system into a python application here:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Since you didn't mention that you can not modify `simple.py` then you would need to automaticly input things **into** the `raw_input()` and the fastest way to do this is simply to pipe in data into the script as "input":

> C:> echo "Alice" | run simple.py

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't mention before that I cannot edit the first file, only the second one, ie, the first one is supposed to always ask the user for input, and I want to make that automatic when using the second script to run the first one several times.

Comment: If you can't edit the first file.. You're out of luck. Perhaps you could pipe in something like `C:> run simple.py < Alice` but that's about it if you can't modify the script.

Comment: Won't `run simple.py < "Alice"` look for a file named `Alice` and try to pull input from that?

Comment: @user2357112 Not sure how windows pipes things.. I only got linux machines to work with but i'd assume it's the same basic principle. Where `"` or `'` is a string, not a command to be executed such as when using: \`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same on Windows and Unix. `Alice` wouldn't be treated as a command on either; quoted or not, it would be considered a file name.

Comment: @user2357112 Yepp my bad, you'd have to echo and pipe after that in order to get python to read it as `stdin` :) Well spotted!

Answer (score 10):

For a case as simple as `simple.py`, you should be able to use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess

child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'simple.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
child.communicate('Alice')
```

For more complex cases, the [Pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) module may be useful. It helps automate interaction with normally-interactive programs by providing more convenient, robust interfaces to send input, wait for prompts, and read output. It should work in cases where `Popen` doesn't work or is more annoying.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('python simple.py')
child.expect("your name?")
child.sendline('Alice')
```

Comment: As you have provided input to the child using the communicate, then how to capture the output of the child and print in this script

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither of the answers above worked for me so I came up with a third solution for others to try.

To send inputs from one python file to another (python version 3.7), I used three files.

1. File for running the subprocess
2. File for outputs (very simple)
3. File that needs the inputs

Here are the three files in the same order as above.

You don't need to print out the output, but I'll include the terminal output below the file examples.
The subprocess file:

```py
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

p1 = Popen(["python","output_file.py"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["python", "input_file.py"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()

output = p2.communicate()[0]

print(output)
```

The output file is very simple and there may be a way to work around it. Nevertheless, here is my version:

```py
print(1)
print(2)
print('My String')
```

The input file requires type casting for numbers.

```py
i = input('Enter a number: ')
j = input('Enter another: ')
k = int(i) + int(j)
print(k)
l = input('Tell me something. ')
print(l)
```

Here is the terminal output:

```
b'Enter a number: Enter another: 3\r\nTell me something. My String!\r\n'
```